# Tensile strength of a chain of electromagnets

Tags: electromagnetism, forces, material-science

I was having a discussion about the tensile strengths of various materials.

Could something like a chain of electromagnets be made to have a tensile strength proportional to the power applied to it?

Comment: Why proportional to the power? If it's superconducting magnets, then it's zero power and if it is ordinary copper wound magnets it would be closer to $\propto \sqrt P$. And if you want to go zero to hero, just use permanent magnets and save yourself power, cooling and cost.

Comment: My curiousity sprung when I read about the Launch Loop and other orbital elevator concepts. So in this hypothetical case,  something like ordinary copper wound magnets.

Comment: I doubt that ordinary conductors are even close to the requirements of magnetic launch assist systems. There is probably a two or three orders of magnitude disadvantage to superconductors there.

Answer (score 2):

Yes.

Is this a useful method in practice to increase the strength to weight ratio of a cable? No, except possibly with the use of superconductors (copper would melt before contributing as much tensile strength as a cable of the same weight).

Comment: S0 the power running through the cable/tube would be used to cool the magnets, rather than the magnetic fields themselves. Could a "superconducting tube of magnets" like this be scaled up for something like a space elevator cable?